# Yet another IMDB crawler using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, imdb

Faced couple issues when trying to crawl imdb, on which didnt found answers here.

Im trying to grab some data from pages like: http://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=1950&page=1 with following code:

```
import scrapy
from tutorial.items import MovieItem, CastItem

class tutorialSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "tutorial"
    allowed_domains = ["imdb.com"]

    # generate start_urls dynamically
    def start_requests(self):
        for year in range(1950, 1951):
            for page in range(1, 3):
                yield scrapy.Request('http://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=%s&page=%s' % (year, page))


    def parse(self, response):
    self.wanted_num=50
        for sel in response.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'lister-item-content')]"):
            item = MovieItem()
            item['Title'] = sel.xpath('h3/a/text()').extract()[0]
            item['Rating'] = sel.xpath('div[@class="ratings-bar"]/div[@name="ir"]/strong/text()').extract()[0]
            item['Ranking']=sel.xpath('h3/span[@class="lister-item-index unbold text-primary"]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['ReleaseDate'] = sel.xpath('h3/span[@class="lister-item-year text-muted unbold"]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['MianPageUrl'] = "http://imdb.com"+sel.xpath('h3/a/@href').extract()[0]
            request = scrapy.Request(item['MianPageUrl'], callback=self.parseMovieDetails)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            if int(item['Ranking']) >= self.wanted_num + 1:
                return
        yield request
```

So, questions here are:

1. It seems to be going into infinite loop while trying to crawl on these pages(301 redirects), and I dont know why?(
2. I suspect that ranking should be trimmed, as from page it will come as '1.', so how I cut that point at the end of string?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Could you post crawl log? You can do this via `scrapy crawl spider -s LOG_FILE=output.log` or `scrapy crawl spider &> output.log` commands.

Comment: Hi, strange things happening :-) now it works!  As for question #2 ive fixed it by : `item['Ranking']=re.match(r'(^[0-9]+)',sel.xpath('h3/span[@class="lister-item-index unbold text-primary"]/text()').extract()[0].__str__().strip()).group(1)`

Comment: FYI: scrapy selectors already have inbuilt `regex` shortcut, e.g.: `sel.xpath('//div').re('someregex')`

Comment: Thanks! didnt know that